# Installing Eclipse Mars on 16.04

Tags: software-installation, java, eclipse

So I realized the eclipse version in the repositories is pretty old and I'm trying to upgrade to the current version. Every tutorial I've read basically has you download the installer as a tar.gz extract and then run the installer or application. When I follow these steps I can't run the eclipse file. I have oracle JRE and JDK 8 installed so I'm not exactly sure what is going on here and why I can't run it.

Anyway any help is appreciated, and I've attached a screenshot to get more of an idea what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean you can't run it? What happens? Also, run it from your home dir, not this other partition. I'm not sure encoded links will work from another partition.

Comment: I used the Eclipse installer, looks like you have used a different file. Try either 32bit or 64bit installer....

Answer (score 1):

So currently with Eclipse on 16.04 there is a [known GTK3 issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/swt-gtk/+bug/1552764). There are a number of ways to work around this issue, but it looks like you just want to click Eclipse icon and work away. In your eclipse directory as above, open the `eclipse.ini` file. Add:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

before `--launcher.appendVmargs`

This will tell eclipse to launch with GTK2 instead.

As you're upgrading Eclipse by not using the Ubuntu repos (a very good move, MARS has a very retina friendly dark theme) when you try to run Eclipse you may get prompted for a jre. Simply unzip your latest downloaded JDK and open it to find the jre folder. Copy and paste the jre folder into your eclipse directory. Double click the eclipse icon and it should run perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what the issue is with your installation, but if you run the "eclipse" executable (you know, the one with the gear icon) it should work.

However, you might like to check out "ubuntu make" (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) to install eclipse. Then you get a nice starter in your dash/launcher.